# datagrid with Comboboxcolumn - AddNew Error

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox

Using EF 4, C# WinForms, and Northwind database, I bound a datagrid to Orders Entity, then at runtime I created a new Comboboxcolum.

```
    Entities NW;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NW = new Entities();
        BindingSource1.DataSource = NW.Orders;

        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn CboCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
        {
            HeaderText = "Customer",
            DataPropertyName = " Customer ID",
            DataSource = NW.Customers.Execute(MergeOption.AppendOnly),
            ValueMember = "CustomerID",
            DisplayMember = "CompanyName"
        };
        Datagriview1.Columns.Insert(1, CboCol);
    }
```

with the above code, I succeeded to change values and delete rows in the datagridview, but could not add new rows by clicking on the "+" button (Add New), Error: "datagridviewcombocell is not a valid value". Is there any idea please ?

Comment: What code is run on that "+" button's click event? On what line does the error happen?

Comment: databindingNavigator Add button with no additional code, no line number is indicated by the compiler

Answer (score 0):

Because you bind the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn with data, so when you add a new row which contains some null value is not found in your data source, and that's why it prompt you is not a valid value

My suggestion is not adding the new record into the DataGirdViewComboBox directly but the data source that you bind into the combo box. It is good to keep your DataGridViewComboBox as read only always when you bind it from a data source.

Comment: datagridview is bound to databinding source at design time, and the property of databindingNavigator1.AddNewItem = bindingNavigatorAddNewItem, I tried with setting the DataGridViewComboBox as read only, result remains the same.

Comment: I've tried to redo this more simple, please look at this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10657095/comboboxcolumn-created-using-the-designer]